# The length of subjects and complements when using a to-infinitive as part of a subject

Tags: syntactic-analysis

@Kalenda gives explanations and some examples of using the to-infinitive in the post:
[Can I start a sentence with To + verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389720/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-to-verb/389916#389916?newreg=a26cc4c9462948d9a92deaf07c376d63)

> To question one's existence would be natural
>
> To start a sentence with an infinitive is bizarre
>
> To talk to one's boss in the morning is every employee's desire

I wonder: Is the length of subjects before / complements etc after the 'be' critical here? Say,

`To speak  of ... [long subject] ... is ... long complement`.

Is this good in English? I met examples when the first complement in `To speak of ... is ...` was very long.

Comment: Weighty subjects of any form are usually avoided in English. As are weighty complements. It's a matter of style (but bordering on idiomaticity) rather than grammaticality.

Comment: You're worried of the length of complements! Which complements? What's actually your question?

Comment: Just length. Here is an example: `To speak of rigorous separation and a willingness to abandon part of what was hitherto one’s own but has become dangerous is to use the classic language of anxiety`. The complement of `To speak of ...` here is quite long. Is this bad? And the same question is about what is after `is` here or in my main question. It has been marked there as `long complement` at the end of sentence.

Comment: @user2626, it's really lengthy! **Edwin Ashworth's** comment above serves as an answer. It's always better to rephrase and reduce this kind of sentences.

Comment: Generally, lengthy items are best located at the end of the clause where they are easier to process.

Answer (score 1):

> To be or not to be, that is the question.

You can certainly start a sentence with To + a verb, and it's not all that uncommon. It's often used as an abbreviated version of a sentence that begins with "If you want to ..." For example:

> [If you want] To understand his mental state at the time of the
>   murder, you must experience the pain he felt that morning.
>
> [If you want] To find fire, look for smoke.

I don't believe the length of the subject has any impact on its use.