# Which one is more appropriate: To learn more about or For more information

Tags: grammar, formality

When sending a formal email, which of the following sentences is more appropriate to use:

> 1. To learn more information, please visit helloworld.com.
> 2. For more information, please visit helloworld.com

Also, using `To learn more information...` has any grammatical issue? Is there any reason why you should not start a sentence with an Infinitive Verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my ears "for more information..." sounds more natural. An [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20learn%20more%20information%2Cfor%20more%20information&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20learn%20more%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20more%20information%3B%2Cc0) with both phrases shows that "for more information" is far more common. I would probably use "for more information," even though neither are wrong per se.

To answer the other question, there is nothing ungrammatical about starting a sentence with an infinitive, as discussed in this post: [Can I start a sentence with To + verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389720/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-to-verb).

Comment: I've just run an Ngram with "learn more information" on its own and got the response "no valid ngrams to plot" which confirms my opinion that it isn't used at all. I also ran one for "learn information" and got a series of really tiny peaks starting in about 1970. I was surprised to find any hits at all as I believe that one _learns facts_ by _gaining information_ and then retaining the information in one's memory. Gaining information is only the first stage in learning facts in much the same way as eating food is only the first stage of gaining nourishment, there's a lot of digesting to do.

Comment: The idiomatic expression is "To learn more" minus the "information" so it's unsurprising that "learn more information" came up short.  Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+learn+more%2C+for+more+information&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3 shows that "to learn more" was more popular than "for more information" up to 1987.  Sorry, I don't know how to put links in comments.